# TreeSet to LinkedHashSet using sorting parameters, how to write stream function

Tags: java

I have a very simple class, called customer:

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{
    public String customerName;

    public Customer(String customerName){
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer o) {
        return customerName.compareTo(o.customerName);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my code I have a TreeSet of those customers and a String with all customerNames (sorted). I need to transform `TreeSet<Customer>` into `LinkedHashSet<Customer>`, using streams.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // All customers as a TreeSet
        TreeSet<Customer> custTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Mary"));
        custTreeSet.add(new Customer("John"));
        custTreeSet.add(new Customer("David"));
        custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Andrew"));
        custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Bill"));

        // All names of customers
        String allNames = "Bill/Andrew/David/John/Mary";

        // Need to get LinkedHashSet, where all customers appear as they are in "allNames" variable
        LinkedHashSet<Customer> custLinkedSet = sortCustomers(custTreeSet, allNames);

    }

    /*
    * How can I refactor this code using stream?
    * i.e. conversion from TreeSet => LinkedHashSet, accorging to names in string
    * */
    public static LinkedHashSet<Customer> sortCustomers(TreeSet<Customer> inputTreeSet, String custOrder){
        LinkedHashSet<Customer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        String[] allnames = custOrder.split("/");
        for (int i = 0; i<allnames.length; i++) {
            String currentName = allnames[i];
            System.out.println(currentName);
            for (Customer cust : inputTreeSet){
                if (cust.customerName.equals(currentName)){
                    result.add(cust);
                    System.out.println("added");
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I refactor `sortCustomers` method? I need to make it shorter and use streams.

Comment: Note: if you need to use angle brackets like `TreeSet<Customer>`, you need to put them in backticks, otherwise they will be interpreted as (invalid) HTML.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why do you need your original TreeSet?

```
LinkedHashSet<Customer> lhs = Arrays.stream( 
    custOrder.split("/") 
).map(Customer::new).collect( 
    Collectors.toCollection(
          LinkedHashSet::new
    )
);
```

If you must use the orginal TreeSet replace the map by a map that gets the corresponding Customer from the tree set.

```
LinkedHashSet<Customer> lhs = Arrays.stream( 
    custOrder.split("/") 
).map( string ->{
        return inputTreeSet.stream().filter( 
            customer -> string.equals( 
                customer.customerName() 
            ) 
        ).findFirst() 
    }
).filter( 
    Optional::isPresent 
).map( Optional::get ).collect(
    Collectors.toCollection(
          LinkedHashSet::new
    )
);
```

Comment: Sorry, it just an example. Initial class is very big and complicated.

Comment: @Gennadiy I've updated it to include more in the 'map' function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. It simply takes the supplied name list and for each name in that list, streams the set, filtering for a match, then using the first one found.

If no match is found, a new customer is created and passed along in the stream.

```
LinkedHashSet<Customer> custLinkedSet = sortCustomers(custTreeSet, allNames);

    public static Set<Customer> sortCustomers(Set<Customer> set, String nameList) {
       return Arrays.stream(nameList.split("/"))
            .map(name -> set.stream()
            .filter(cust -> cust.customerName.equals(name))
                // if customer not found, create a new one using
                // that customer's name
                .findFirst().orElse(new Customer(name)))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Of course, it would be much more efficient if you would simply create the `Set` in the proper order from the beginning.  You could specify an order list by which to sort the customers.    Here is an example:

Create a map of the names associated with a number representing the order of the name.

```
String allNames = "Bill/Andrew/David/John/Mary";
String[] names = allNames.split("/");
Map<String,Integer> sortMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    sortMap.put(names[i],i);
}
```

The `sortMap` looks like the following with the number indicating order

```
Andrew=1
Bill=0
David=2
John=3
Mary=4
```

Now use that map to govern the sort by creating a Comparator.  Instead of sorting on the name, the sort is on the value for that name.

```
Comparator<Customer> comp = 
            Comparator.comparing(cust-> sortMap.get(cust.customerName));
```

And now you can add the customers to a `TreeSort` using the comparator. How you add them does not matter as they will be sorted according to the `sortMap`

```
TreeSet<Customer> custTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(comp);

custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Mary"));
custTreeSet.add(new Customer("John"));
custTreeSet.add(new Customer("David"));
custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Andrew"));
custTreeSet.add(new Customer("Bill"));

custTreeSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Bill
Andrew
David
John
Mary
```

You could also just assign an `id` to each `Customer` object and use that for sorting.